# Escape '&' when filling in a docx document using PHPWord

Tags: regex, string, escaping, phpword, phpoffice

I am building a web application which has to fill in a docx document. I am using the TemplateProcessor provided by PHPWord which takes a specific hook presenting on the document and replaces it with a given string. The problem that I have is when in the string an "&" is presenting - the document gets corrupted because of missing ';'.

The functions which I use to clear up the string are

```
$string = trim(html_entity_decode($string));
$string = strip_tags($string);
$string = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string));
```

Does anyone has an idea how I can escape the ampersant symbol so the file will not get corrupted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly: see [this HTML Entity chart](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref):

```
$str = preg_replace( '/&/', '&amp;', $str );
```

In your case however, it's better to add this line using [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php):

```
$str = htmlspecialchars( $str );
```

Comment: Thank you this has fixed my issue!